# Browserify with typescript modules - what are best design practices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, typescript, browserify

I've got a browserify javascript project, where I include modules with the `require` statement. I'm now adding in some typescript, and it's working fine when I simply `require` the compiled javascript.

But typescript also has its own `module` statement. How does this relate to browserify/node's modules? Should I be using both? That seems redundant. Which type of modules should be used, and under what circumstances?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of TypeScript (1.5) the `module` is deprecated in favour of `namespace` keyword. The keyword is to be used to create internal modules - allows you to organise your code internally.

So now it is more obvious that those are different things. Still TypeScript provides ability to create browserify/node's modules - external modules. For that you can use [ES6 module syntax](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#es6-modules) or older TypeScript's syntax. Then use browserify plugin (such as tsify) for more convenient builds.

More documentation about TypeScript modules and namespaces can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md) (also describing the older external modules syntax)

Which type of modules should be used depends on the project and taste of developers. If you target Node.js it worth to use CommonJS modules (IMHO ES6 syntax in TS and transpile it to CommonJS). If you are using browserify it is reasonable to use external modules, too. Namespaces is recommended to use only inside one file - hence internal modules.

Comment: So if I've got this right, you're suggesting using tsify, and then simply replacing `var stuff = require('./compiledStuff.js')`, with `import * as stuff from "./rawStuff"`, which will basically just transpile to the former. And then use typescript namespaces as needed for further internal organization.

Comment: This approach seems to work well, thanks. Looking at the compiled typescript, it has indeed just changed the `import` statements into `requires`. Anyone using this approach should be very careful to use consistent capitalizations across all `imports` (or `requires`). If you don't, the compiler won't complain, but it will actually generate multiple separate namespaces, one for each capitalization pattern.